# how to give unique id for dynamically appending cards

Tags: jquery

I was writing a code to append a card with a new header every time a button is pressed also the header is dynamically providing by user. the problem is i cant make the function work properly for more than one card. I know the problem is that every card has the same class hence the new header will be appended to each card.I also want to add different user input lists to these cards.

```
 $(".add").click(function(){
        let list = $("#userInp").val()
        $("#mainCard").append('<div class="card col-xl-3"  ><div class="card-header" id ="head" ></div><div class="card body" ><ul></ul></div></div>')
        $("#mainCard").find("#head").append('<button type = "checkbox" class ="form-check-input" id = "checkbox01"></button>'+list+'')

})
```

This is my code.And thanks for helping me.

Comment: Just create a global ID and increment it with every new card. Give the card id a prefix plus the incremented number.

Comment: Please note a button can not have a type of checkbox  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can skip the head id all together. Work with a [document fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) and you are contained to working with just what you are adding.

**NOTE** the code below is untested and may need some tweaking.

```
$(".add").click(function(){
    //Create the fragment
    let frag = new DocumentFragment();
    let list = $("#userInp").val();
    //Append the card to the fragment
    $(frag).append('<div class="card col-xl-3"><div class="card-header"></div><div class="card body" ><ul></ul></div></div>');
    //Add the control to the card-header element
    $(frag).find(".card-header").append('<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="checkbox' + $("#mainCard.card").length + '">'+list+'');
    //Finally append the fragment to the main card
    $("#mainCard").append(frag);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check existing length of the cards like below

```
$(".add").click(function(){
        let cardCount=$("#mainCard.card").length;
        let list = $("#userInp").val()
        $("#mainCard").append('<div class="card col-xl-3"  ><div class="card-header" id ="head"+(cardCount+1) ></div><div class="card body" ><ul></ul></div></div>')
        $("#mainCard").find("#head"+(cardCount+1)).append('<button type = "checkbox" class ="form-check-input" id = "checkbox01"></button>'+list+'')

})
```

Comment: You answer is almost correct, but you don't need `+""` and second, in the append, you need to redo `"head"+(cardCount+1)+""` to `"head'+(cardCount+1)+'`

Comment: Your `.find("#head'+(cardCount+1)+'")` should be `.find("#head"+(cardCount+1))`. Also `$("#mainCard.card").length;` needs to be `$("#mainCard .card").length;`

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```
$(".add").click(function() {
  var list = $("#userInp").val();
  var count = $("#mainCard .card").length + 1;
  count = count > 10 ? count : "0" + count;
  var card = $("<div>", {
    class: "card col-xl-3"
  }).appendTo("#mainCard");
  $("<div>", {
    class: "card-header",
    id: "header-" + count
  }).appendTo(card);
  $("<div>", {
    class: "card-body"
  }).appendTo(card);
  $("<ul>").appendTo($(".card-body", card));
  $("<button>", {
    type: "checkbox",
    class: "form-check-input",
    id: "checkbox-" + count
  }).appendTo($(".card-header", card));
});
```